# How to import css file of react-datepicker into SSR written in Nestjs and AdminJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, datepicker, nestjs

I am using the react-datapicker inside of SSR project written in Nest.js and Admin.js. I need to add some React components so I need to import **import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'** into the project so that  should work properly with proper design. The error is says **[Nest] 93478  - 02/12/2022, 12:47:22 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Unexpected character '@' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)**. I could not find any solution specific to my problem. Is there anyone can help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Please share some example code.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue today i copied the all css in react-date-picker and pasted into local css file.

> ```
> assets: {
>   styles: ['/styles/index.css', '/styles/react-date-picker.css'],
>   scripts: ['/scripts/index.js'],
> },
> ```